# try, catch doesent seem to work

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following code which I thought would allow me to catch an error and instead of generating the error write out "An Error Occurred".

Unfortunately, it still shows the error "Failed to restart the computer: Access is denied" instead.

I know why this is happening but I want to be able to catch the error and reformat it. What am I doing wrong?

```
try {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName MFG-KY-PC74 -Force 
} catch {
    Write-Host "An Error Occurred"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In PowerShell there are terminating and non-terminating errors. The former terminate script execution (if not caught) and can be caught by `try..catch`, the latter don't terminate script execution (so there's nothing to catch). The error you're receiving is a non-terminating one, so you need to make it a terminating error by appending `-ErrorAction Stop` to the statement:

```
try {
  Restart-Computer -ComputerName MFG-KY-PC74 -Force -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
  write-host "An Error Occurred"
}
```

Alternatively you can set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` if you want all errors to become terminating errors.

See [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/03/08/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-erroractionpreference-to-control-cmdlet-handling-of-errors/) on the *Scripting Guy* blog for more information.

Comment: Ansgar you are a star, thank you so much. That answers the question perfectly. I am learning slowly :)