# Try Catch output

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm trying to use the try and catch method so when a host is unlivable rather then just skipping over it the script will display.  This is not working as intended, any ideas?

```
#Gets list of machines from specified OU
Function Get-CompList{
Get-ADObject -Filter { ObjectClass -eq "computer" } -SearchBase "OU=Resources,DC=NWTraders,DC=LOCAL" `
| Select-Object -expandproperty Name
}

#Gets Admin accounts from computer in OU from Get-Complist function
Function Get-AdminGroups{

foreach($i in Get-CompList){
Try{

$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$i"
$Object = $adsi.Children | ? {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | % {
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        ComputerName = $i -join ''
        UserName = $_.Name -join ''
        Groups = ($_.Groups()  |Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ',' 
          }  
      } 


   $Object |? {$_.Groups -match "Administrators*"}  
   "`r"
  }

Catch{
"$i is unavalible"
"`r"
     }
  }
}

Get-AdminGroups
```

Comment: How *exactly* is it "not working"? Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19543621/1630171) help?

Comment: Nothing shows for the Catch it just skips over instead of telling me the specific machine is unavailable.

Comment: I just answered a very similar question yesterday. Short version: Test for connectivity via a ping *before* attempting to connect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939886/powershell-try-catch-continue/19940246#19940246

Comment: thanks that did the trick, but I did notice you left out a ) in your if statement.